# How much can i custom ads in flutter with Firebase AdMob?

Tags: flutter, firebase, admob

Is it possible to custom the image, the title, the description etc of the ad ?

I'm working for a hairdresser app and i need to show ads of hairdresser brand (i have a client and my client will get partnership with these brands so i want to show ads only for them)

I implemented today a banner and a native ad into my app, but i didn't found how custom them.

Thanks you in advance !

Impleting ads using Firebase Admob into Flutter app -> custom very specifically these ads.

Comment: It's not possible to custom them. what you can do is add tags to show a "related" content in your ads.

Comment: I told my client is it possible to make custom ads for the partnerships.

I think i have to find another solution now :(

Comment: If you want to have "Custom ads" you can make your own class where you display the ads that you want but you won't be able to manage them with admob

Comment: Yes i think i'll try something like that.

What do you think to do my own Firebase events for ad clicked/opened ?
Because i have to tracks these stats for my client continue partnership with the brands.

Comment: You have to track the views also and maybe some geo info to show them in certain areas